# Exim - Restrict outgoing email to be from only one address

Tags: email, cpanel, email-validation, spam-prevention, exim

A bot has found a way to send bulk spam through my server. My server is not an open relay. All mails are coming from localhost. The emails are being sent from a series of FIRSTNAME_LASTNAME@mydomain.com. At mydomain, there is only 1 email account that was created that we send from.

Is there a way to restrict outgoing email that are being sent through exim to only allow emails to be sent from the 1 email account we created and block all other Sent From addressed that are being created?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the next condition to your SMTP router(s):

```
condition = ${if match{$sender_address}{legal@mydomain.com}{yes}{no}}
```

Comment: Where specifically do I need to put this?

Comment: It depends on the distribution you have used. `Exim` have `routers` that route message accordingly to the conditions. You have to find outgoing router and add the proposed line to it to restrict it to the specified sender.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by turning on X-Headers which allowed me to locate where the emails were being executed from which in turn allowed me to eliminate an exploit from an old script.